# utf8 not working with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8

When I echo arabic characters they appear fine but If I echo them from the database they appear as question marks. Here is what I did so far but it is still not working:

charset setting now is:

```
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
```

collation setting now is:

```
| Variable_name        | Value           |
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
```

In the PHP code I use:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
mysql_query("set character_set_server='utf-8'");
mysql_query("set_names 'utf8'");
```

More info:

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: I don't know what you've done but you don't run `set names utf8`; you run `set_names 'utf8'` (note the underscore).

Comment: Note that MySQL does not speak the same language as everyone else. When MySQL says "utf8" it really means "some weirdly retarded variant of UTF-8 that is limited to three bytes for god knows what ridiculous reason". If you really want UTF-8 you should tell MySQL that you want this weird thing MySQL likes to call [utf8mb4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes hahahaha nice joke. That one is really funny. Why are you looking at me like that? Oh... that's... not a joke? Oh...

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Of course it's a joke. I thought it was obvious when I mentioned "MySQL".

Comment: I transfered the database and the code to a different server and everything worked just fine!

I guess there is something wrong with the mysql installation!

Thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

> I echo them from the database they appear as question marks

How are you echo'ing them? What is the encoding of the thing you're echo'ing to? If you're echo'ing to HTML make sure the HTML page is interpretted at UTF8.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Yes I just echo them within HTML tags. something like echo'<p>' . $row['title'] . '</p>/;

SHould not this line encode it to utf8:

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

IF not, how can I make sure that HTML is interpreted as UTF-8?

Also in the same page I echo Arabic characters directly and they appear fine.

Comment: You could add `<meta charset="utf-8">` too but I think browser are supposed to respect the `Content-Type charset` header. You can check which encoding your browser has applied. For Chrome it's `Options > Tools > Encoding`

Comment: @MohamedGamalAbdalkader the `header/meta charset` does not encode anything, it *announces* what encoding you are using. So if you announce UTF-8, and see question marks, your data was not encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: I transfered the database and the code to a different server and everything worked just fine!

I guess there is something wrong with the mysql installation!

Thanks for your help anyways!